# Is there a better way to retrieve just a model values?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Movie model has property `watched` with a `value` i.e `{watched: 12345}`
Movie model also referencing a user model.

If I want to retrieve all the ids ('watched' values) I have to do something like this which works fine:

```
  const res = await Movie.find({ user: user.id }).select('watched -_id')
  const watched = res.map(w => w.watched)
  console.log(watched) // [123343, 34546, 45656]
```

Is there a better way to retrieve just model values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
const watched = await Movie.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "user": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user.id) }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "watchedIds": { "$push": "$watched" }
  }}
])

console.log(watched[0].watchedIds) // [123343, 34546, 45656]
```

But I can say there is no performance issue in the query you have used and the above one.